# in angular , .asObservable() function not return true value

Tags: angular

i'm new in angular,my service is this:

```
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


export class DbSrvConnService {
        user_title=new Subject<any>();
        constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


send_user(value)
  {
    this.user_title.next(value);
    console.log(value);
  } 
 get_user():Observable<any>{
    console.log(this.user_title.asObservable());
    return this.user_title.asObservable();
  }
```

in send_user() function true value write in console but in get_user() in console recive :

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Subject}
```

in component that call service i do this:

```
constructor(private DbSrvConnService:DbSrvConnService) { 
    this.DbSrvConnService.get_user().subscribe(
      (result)=>{
        alert(result);
      }
    )
  }
```

but no alert is displayed

Comment: do you get your alert? what do you publish (object, string, number)?

Answer (score 0):

`asObservable` returns an Observable. In order to get the latest value from an Observable, you need to subscribe.

```
this.<serviceName>.get_user().subscribe(result=>{
// here you find the observable latest value

})
```

Comment: in component that call service i do this

Answer (score 0):

RxJS `subject` would only emit to the future notifications to subscribers. If you wish to emit something to the subscribers as soon as they subscribe, look into RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject).

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DbSrvConnService {
  user_title = new BehaviorSubject<any>('default'); // <-- default value
  ...
}
```

If you do not wish to have a default value, you could use RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1. It would buffer and emit the last value to future subscribers.

```js
import { ReplaySubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DbSrvConnService {
  user_title = new ReplaySubject<any>(1); // <-- buffer 1
  ...
}
```

**Edit**: Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pp5tfp?file=src/app/db-srv-conn.service.ts)

Comment: no ,not work ,massage in console :ReplaySubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}

Comment: @mahdi.gh: `ReplaySubject` needs atleast one emission for it to buffer. Are you calling `send_user()` anywhere?

Comment: @mahdi.gh: It works in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pp5tfp?file=src/app/db-srv-conn.service.ts). You could notice I've called the `send_user()` function in the service constructor as an example. If your code still doesn't work you'd need to show where you're calling the `send_user()` function.